# open pdf via pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/helloworld.html
here is a guide how to open pdf files in related folder. I want to open file from absolute path. like

```
var src = "C:\path\path\file.pdf";
```

how can I do it?
I already try with absolute path but there was an error while downloading file via ajax request

Comment: You can't access local file system via javascript.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme, and what about storage? on storage i have a folder where documents are. like
http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/pdffiles/mypdf.PDF

Comment: Access to remote domains forbidden (unless the server which host files has CORS headers set). (For web developers-beginners and) for simplicity  the PDF.js viewer and PDF files shall be hosted on the same web server... unless you know web browser security model.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pdf via AJAX on server and after that open it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can load local pdf and view it in the browser without uploading. I did not believe it was possible due to browser security but in fact it does work....

http://www.pdfcharts.com/lab/analyze.html